# Nodejs + Angular 6 + Nginx: Error 500 when loading static files

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, angular6

When the page tries to load the statics file, I get a error 500. Keep in mind, that the index.html does loads, but everything else doesnt. This is the error im getting:

`GET https://url/styles.27d4d011b38e19393988.css 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Note: When I access the webapp tru the 'normal' url (http://url:3000) the app works.

Bellow my nginx config

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server;
            listen 443 ssl;

            ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

            server_name _;

            root /var/www/html;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                    proxy_http_version 1.1;
                    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            }

}
```

My server.js. '/' is the path to my angular application.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
const isLoggedIn = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.redirect('/auth');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname));
  // res.send('test');
});

app.get('/auth', passport.authenticate('oauth2-cognito'), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/');
  // res.send('test');
});

//add basic
const server = http.createServer(app);
// const serverhttps = https.createServer(app);

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server running on: ' + port);
});
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you try doing this & tell us what happens? Does this work? `http://url:3000/styles.27d4d011b38e19393988.css`

Comment: It does work. The browser access the css file.

Comment: Ok cool, so does that answer your query, or are you trying to achieve something more here?

Comment: I'm trying to access my webapp through the basic URL(without the port) which, the index.html works, but the statics files wont load or access (errror 500)

Comment: Try removing the `try_files` statement.

Comment: @RichardSmith that worked! Thanks